# Match a pattern and replace the first instance of string following it (regardless of spaces or tabs)

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression, perl

I asked a similar question a while back but I'm hitting a brick wall getting this one to work.

I'm scripting the modification of a config file laid out like this:

```
[Thing1]
    [[subthingA]]
        this = 0
        that = string
        and = localhost
        the = 80
        other = 0
        thing_ading = /path/to/a/dir

[Thing2]
    [[subthingB]]
        this = 0
        thing_ading = /path/to/dir
        here = 0
```

Where there are N number of [Things], often with the same key and/or value of a key/value pair, and the key/value pairs under the [[subthings]] are indented by exactly 8 spaces. I'm specifically trying to craft a one-liner using awk/sed/grep/tr/cut/perl that can change the value of `thing_ading` under `SubthingB` to a different directory path.

I'm able to edit all `thing_adings` and I've been able to target certain pairs, but the spaces are really giving me an issue.

Comment: add expected output as well as code you tried

Comment: You should probably search for "ini-file parser". Add "bash" to the query if you want something for `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tackle such problems using `sed`'s range operator `,`:

```
sed -e '
   /^\[Thing2]$/,/^$/!b
   /^[[:blank:]]\{4\}\[\[subthingB]]/,/^$/s|^\([[:blank:]]\{8\}thing_ading\) = .*|\1 = /YOUR/NEW/PATH/TO/DIR|
' yourinifile
```

- First you select the proper range by skipping improper ranges.
- Then when in proper range, you perform the substitution on the thing_ding variable required.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! (And thanks for the brief explanation as well).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `sed` one-liner:

```
sed '/[[subthingB]]/,/^ *\[/{/thing_ading =/s_=.*_= /your/path/_}' config_file
```

To work only on the `subthingB` block, we address everything from `[[subthingB]]` to the next line starting with `[` after the indent.

Now, for this block, we address the `thing_ading` line and do the replacement, using `_` instead of `/` as delimited for the `s` command to avoid backslashing the replacement to unreadability.

If the `subthingB` block is guaranteed to have an `thing_ading` entry, you can simplify to

```
sed '/[[subthingB]]/,/thing_ading =/{//s_=.*_= /your/path/_}'
```

reusing the last pattern for inner addressing.